# Open a file with notepad through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a file with notepad.

```
const strfilename = "C:\Users\Desktop\abc.txt"

set OFS = myOFSO.OpenTextFile(strfilename)
```

It is displaying

> error code 424

Comment: And `myOFSO` is declared and initialized how?

Comment: And, when you fix that code, it will let you read the contents of that file, supposedly created in Notepad, not launch Notepad itself.

Comment: I have defined it as  Dim myOFSO As Object

Comment: @GSerg - I need to launch the notepad file and read the contents of that file as well. What line should I add to launch that particular notepad file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how did you assign it? I get the error 424 only if I do not use Option Explicit. So, please tell, what you really did!

Answer (score 9):

Could just call a shell command to execute notepad.exe with the file path.

```
returnvalue = Shell("notepad.exe " & strfilename, vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried using shell command earlier, but it wasn't working as I didn't mentioned vbNormalFocus. Now it working fine and I am able to launch the notepad. I hope it will read the contents of the notepad as well?

Comment: This opens Notepad with the file contents displayed.  But it also generates an error: "Object variable or With block variable not set".  How did you initialize the object?

Comment: This should be the only accepted answer. With all due respect to the others, the question asked how to open notepad NOT how to open the default program. I am generating an .sql file. I don't WANT to open it with the default application I want to use *notepad*. This is the only response that works and the only one that answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

### Open any file with the default program for the filetype: <sub><sup>(with a single line of code)</sup></sub>

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open("c:\Users\Desktop\abc.txt")
```

---

**If you want to use this method with a filetype that isn't yet associated with an application:**

- Hit the <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>(Windows Key)
- Start typing *`default`*
- Click "**Default Apps**" ([Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4028161/windows-10-change-default-programs)) or "**Default Programs**" ([Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs))

Comment: I tried a few different sugestions, but this was the only one that would run my .vbs script, thaaaaaanks.

Comment: This is not doing anything....

Answer (score 3):

Below code will help you to open notepad from excel.

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim sfile As String
Set fso = CreateObject("shell.application")
sfile = "C:\Users\Universal\Desktop\test.txt"
fso.Open (sfile)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach

```
Sub Test()
Dim strCont     As String

strCont = LoadFileStr$(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Sample.txt")
Range("A1").Value = strCont
End Sub

Function LoadFileStr$(FN$)
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    LoadFileStr = .OpenTextFile(FN, 1).readall
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a new text-file and want to write into it, you could use this approach:

```
Sub writeToTextFile()
    Dim i As Long
    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\newFile.txt" For Output As #1

    Print #1, "This could be the first line"
    Print #1, "this the second"

    For i = 3 To 10
        Print #1, "this is the " & i & ". line"
    Next

    Close #1
End Sub
```