# How to open recently created csv file in notepad?

Tags: vba

I have a simple code, which creates saves the actual file as csv file in another folder. How can I open this recently created file in notepad after the csv was created?

Here is the code, I tried with Call Shell but it didn't work.

```
 Sub ConvertTocsv()


ChDir "S:\Back Office\Tradar\DailyReportBDP"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    ("S:\Back Office\Tradar\DailyReportBDP\Custom_Daily_Report_BDP_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True, Local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


Information.Show


Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "S:\Back Office\Tradar\DailyReportBDP", vbNormalFocus)


End Sub
```

Please provide some input. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a notepad through vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073436/open-a-notepad-through-vba)

Comment: thanks, but the solution you posted open a specific file. In my case the filename is changing everyday after converting to csv. I can provide the code for the "ConvertoCSV" macro tomorrow.

Comment: Could work with that code. How do I replace strfilename with the recently created csv?




     returnvalue = Shell("notepad.exe " & strfilename, vbNormalFocus)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your code then.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073436/open-a-notepad-through-vba#answer-49073590

Comment: Thank you Meaden, but this only opens a blank notepad. How do I open the recently created csv file in notepad? What should put instead of strfilename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, here:

```
Sub ConvertTocsv()

Dim strfilename As String
strfilename = "S:\Back Office\Tradar\DailyReportBDP\Custom_Daily_Report_BDP_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".csv"

ChDir "S:\Back Office\Tradar\DailyReportBDP"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    ("S:\Back Office\Tradar\DailyReportBDP\Custom_Daily_Report_BDP_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True, Local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True



Information.Show


returnvalue = Shell("notepad.exe " & strfilename, vbNormalFocus)

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```