# Im trying to copy a range of cells in Excel to a blank notepad and im getting an error

Tags: excel, vba

ive tried the below code and keep getting a

> Debug error (Run-Time error '429' ActiveX component cant create
> object)

on

```
Set ojbNotepad = CreateObject(Notepad.Application")
```

```vb
Sub CopyRangeToNotepad()
    Dim objNotepad As Object
    Dim strText As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    ' Set the range that you want to copy
    Set rng = Range("A1:B5")
    
    ' Copy the range to clipboard
    rng.COPY
    
    ' Open Notepad
    **Set objNotepad = CreateObject("Notepad.Application")**
    objNotepad.Visible = True
    
    ' Paste the range into Notepad
    objNotepad.Documents.Add
    objNotepad.Selection.Paste
    
    ' Release the object
    Set objNotepad = Nothing
End Sub
```

any ideas why it keeps doing that?

tried the above and get a debug error

Comment: if usually is a good idea to include the error message you get with your question. - Is it by any chance Runtime-Error 429?

Comment: You cannot use `CreateObject` to create an instance of notepad - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073436/open-a-file-with-notepad-through-vba

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub CopyToNotepad()
    With Application
        Range("A1:B5").Copy
        Shell "Notepad.exe", 3
        SendKeys "^v"
        VBA.AppActivate .Caption 'set focus on Excel Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```